# Multiple endpoints in same query

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

It works perfectly, with a single endpoint.
With apollo-link-rest, I have made a client that looks like this

```
const restLink = new RestLink({ uri: "https://example.com/" })
```

And export the client with a `new ApolloClient({...})`

Now to the question

On the same server `https://example.com/`, there are multiple endpoints, all with same fields but different data in each

The first query that works look like this

```
export const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
   query firstQuery {
    products @rest(type: "data" path: "first/feed") { // the path could be second/feed and it will work with different data
     id
     title
   }
 }
`
```

I want all these different path into one and same json feed, because they all have the same fields, but with different data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using aliases

You can (should be possible) use standard method to make similar queries - get many data (result) nurmally available as the same shape (node name). This is described [here](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/2-more-graphql-concepts/).

```
{ 
  "1": products(....
  "2": products(....
  ...
}
```

Paths can be created [using variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#variables)

Results can be easy combined by iterating over `data` object. Problem? Only for fixed amount (not many) endpoints as query shouldn't be generated by strings manipulations.

### Multiple graphql queries

You can create queries in a loop - parametrized - using `Promise.all()` and apollo-client `client.query(`. Results needs to be combined into one, too.

### Custom fetch

Using [custom fetch](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#custom-fetch) you can create a query taking an array of paths. In this case resolver should use `Promise.all()` on parametrized `fetch` requests. Combined results can be returned as single node (as required).

### Bads

All these methods needs making multiple requests. Problem can be resolved by making server side REST wrapper ([docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/data-source/) or [blog](https://graphql.org/blog/rest-api-graphql-wrapper/#a-server-side-rest-wrapper)).